# Is it possible to add a custom error message when a migration is aborted?

Tags: plugin-development, migration

I've got a plugin migration that returns `false` from its `safeUp()` method when certain conditions aren't met.

Upon returning `false` from the migration, the update stalls, rolls back changes and gives an error screen with a generic error message – i.e. "There was a problem updating your database".

For many users (i.e. those who aren't tech savvy enough to check logs etc.) this message isn't very helpful at all. Is it possible to add a custom message when a migration is aborted?

I've tried throwing an exception inside `safeUp()`, which gets *logged* but does not display on the error screen.

If I use a `die()` statement for the error message, Craft *does* display it on the error screen, but that makes the whole update process halt, which seems like an unsafe thing to do.

I've also attempted to use `craft()->userSession->setError()`, but that doesn't appear to be working, either.

Comment: Great idea! I'm gonna bet this one lands on "feature request" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently not, but as Lindsey points out, that's not a bad idea for a [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com).

Comment: Thanks Brad! I've added a feature request: http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/11499702-add-the-option-to-display-a-custom-error-message-w